# WPF C# - JsonConvert.SerializeObject format with object doesn't work properly

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I want to convert in WPF C# an XML file to a JSON as in the following example:

```
<NAME ID="0" DESC="firstdesc">
  <SUBNAME>
    <SUBNAME2 ID="-1" DESC="minusone">
      <HOME />
    </SUBNAME2>
    <SUBNAME2 ID="1" DESC="first">
      <HOME />
    </SUBNAME2>
    <SUBNAME2 ID="2" DESC="second">
      <HOME />
    </SUBNAME2>
    <SUBNAME2 ID="3" DESC="third">
      <HOME />
    </SUBNAME2>
  </SUBNAME>
</NAME>
```

To:

```
{
    "0": {
        "-1": {
            "L": "minusone",
            "N": {}
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "L": "first",
            "N": {}
        },
        "2": {
            "L": "second",
            "N": {}
        },
        "3": {
            "L": "third",
            "N": {}
        }
    }
}
```

i wrote the following code to do that but it doesn't work:

```
XMLdoc.Load(txtFilePath.Text);
XmlNode node = XMLdoc.SelectSingleNode("NAME");
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node);
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonText, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonText, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

The problem is that XML has both a part before and a part after that I would like to ignore. My aim is to take that piece of code from the file given to me and turn it into JSON as I described above. What am I doing wrong? I can't quite understand why that piece of code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
    var list = jsonParsed["NAME"]["SUBNAME"]["SUBNAME2"];

    Dictionary<string, JObject> dict = list.ToDictionary(l => (string)l["@ID"], l => new JObject(
                 new JProperty("L", l["@DESC"]),
                 new JProperty("N", new JObject())));


    var newObj = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JObject>> {
    {(string)jsonParsed["NAME"]["@ID"],dict}
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

json

```
{
  "0": {
    "-1": {
      "L": "minusone",
      "N": {}
    },
    "1": {
      "L": "first",
      "N": {}
    },
    "2": {
      "L": "second",
      "N": {}
    },
    "3": {
      "L": "third",
      "N": {}
    }
  }
}
```

and you can deserialize it to c#

```
Data data =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

after creating these classes

```
public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
      public Dictionary<string,LN> Dict { get; set; }
}

public partial class LN
{
    [JsonProperty("L")]
    public string L { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("N")]
    public N N { get; set; }
}

public partial class N
{
}
```

Comment: Hi, the code has a problem. It said me Error CS1061 'JObject' does not contain a definition of 'Dump' and no accessible extension method 'Dump' was found that takes a first argument of type 'JObject'. Why? I have imported using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

Comment: @John, Sorry  I removed Dump it was for debugging, you don't need it.

Comment: and if i have multiple <NAME how should i change the code? i tried to insert a for loop but the dictionary tells me there is a duplicate key and gives me an exception. Can you pls help me?

Comment: @John You have to post what you have now. I am sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean by multiple name. I think we have multiple names already.